# Are @font-face rules are usable in it's defined CSS File or usable in other CSS files and inline CSS codes?

Tags: css, font-face

I have a bunch of CSS document, that has some `@font-face` rules, I want to check these `@font-face` which are used and which are not used in a HTML Document or Website. So, should I check these `@font-face`s used in it's defined CSS Document or all CSS Documents with inline Style tags in HTML Document?

The question is, this;

#### File Name: style.css

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'FontAwesome';
    src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0');
    src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.7.0') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0') format('woff2'),
    url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.7.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal
}

/* This tag can use the @font-face, because this .any-class rule in same CSS document */
.any-class {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome',
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

#### File Name: another-style.css

```
/* Can this CSS Class use the @font-face in style.css ? */
.any-other-class {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome',
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

#### File Name: index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <style>
        /* Can this .custom-class CSS Selector use @font-face in style.css ? */
        .custom-class {
            font-family: 'FontAwesome',
            font-weight: normal
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Can this DOM Element use @font-face in style.css? -->
    <p style="font-family: 'FontAwesome'; font-weight: normal;">Hello!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sadly, no
the files are different so you wont be able to do this in CSS.
You can try out SASS which allows you to create partial files and collectively form a CSS file.

Comment: @Joykal Infotech: That's not true. It will still work even when they are in separate files, as long as you include them all, whether using `link` in HTML as shown in the question or using `@import` in CSS. You don't need Sass for any of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, everything you have here will just work, as long as you include style.css wherever you want to use your web font, e.g. the way you have done using `link`. Your `@font-face` rule, like any other CSS rule, does not have to appear in the same stylesheet as the CSS rules that reference it, or in any HTML with inline styles that reference it.